# What is relevant difference between Hilbert module and Hilbert space?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that any Hilbert space is a [Hilbert $C*$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_C*-module)
Ok, but I don't sure if every Hilbert module need to be always a Hilbert space and I don't know if it is correct to ask this.

For example, let A be a $C*$-algebra and let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Then $H$⊗$A$ , the tensor product of $H$ to $A$ is a(right) Hilber $C*$- module over $A$.

Some questions:

Every $C*$-algebra $A$ is a Hilbert module over itself: the inner product is given by

$⟨a,b⟩=a∗b(a,b∈A)$ .

For example, take $A$ to be the algebra of continuous functions on some compact space.

- When the space has at least two points, it is not isometric to a Hilbert space ?
- When the compact space is infinite, it is not even isomorphic to a Hilbert space as a Banach space.

I don't understand why well this. In that sense "it is not isometric" to a Hilbert space?

Final question:

- What powerful theoretical applications do Hilbert modules have and why choose them instead of "limited" Hilbert spaces?

Comment: What is the definition of Hilbert module?

Comment: Added a hyperlink to a wikipedia definition.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?